# weird css-issue in Firefox, goes away when inspecting element

Tags: css, macos, firefox, menu, inspector

on a site I built I have a strange issue.
Until recently a specific menu was working like I expected.
But today I saw there goes something wrong on Firefox for Mac now.
I checked the site Safari and Chrome for Mac, an no problem there.
The weird thing that happens is that the links in the menu drop out of sight, except the one page that has childpages (which are not shown in this menubar).
So I think: I will use the 'inspect element' to see if I can find the problem. But the second I inspect an element the menubar looks like it should. I close the inspector and it is back to trouble again.

Any tips or insights would be helpful!
The site is http://www.wij30.nl

Comment: update:
I use Firefox 39. If I check using Saucelab with Firefox 38: no problems. Could it be some bug in Firefox 39?
On the other hand: I think I should be able to make it work, since the menu reappears if I make my screen smaller. Just annoying that I cannot use thi inspector to try some stuff, because the issue disappears when I use the inspector.

Comment: which menu/link you are talking about?  screenshot of issue?

Comment: Reproduced on Ubuntu 15.04 (Firefox 38.0).

Comment: @Leothelion
FIrefox 39 on mac: http://pho.to/9Yhcj 
How it should be: http://pho.to/9Yhcu

Comment: For me its working fine..m testing in ff 39.0

Comment: @Leothelion on Mac or other platform?

Comment: sry i din try in mac..trying in mac now

Comment: @Leothelion thanks for your help! any insights?

Comment: sorry was in office so couldn't get more time but till now i got the point that if i will resize the browser then menu will be display as normal..but after refresh issue will be there.. :(

Comment: yes, that is exactly wat happens here... So far I have not encountered similar problems in other sites, so I guess it must be something conflicting between my css and this particular version of firefox. Guess I will have to do some more trial and error stuff and hope that I can fix it. At least now I know that it is not just on my computer. So thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I fixed it, well actually I found a work-around.
The point was not that the only link that was shown was one that had child-pages. It was the one link that consisted of more than one word. And for some obscure reason it broke into 2 lines in Firefox38 for Mac. ("over WIJ" in the first line and "3.0" in the second line). Moving all the items that contained only one word down the line.
Adding some none-breaking spaces in the menu label fixed the problem for now.
But like I said: really a work-around not really a problem-solver.
If someone can tell me why Firefox38 for Mac made this happen: please tell. Thanks!